# Angular-Cli, Webpack: Why Karma-coverage including lib folder

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, karma-runner, angular-cli, karma-coverage

we recently moved to use angular-cli beta 18. As per the direction given in docs, we made changes to run our tests. As of now below is our directory structure

```
root
-coverage
-src
--app
---component
----mycomp.ts
----mycomp.spec.ts
---lib
----angular
----rxjs
--index.html
--test.ts
--tsconfig.json
-karma.conf.js
-package.json
```

as suggested in angular-cli documentation, we are using test.ts to include all tests. the context setting line is

```
.then(()=> require.context('./../src', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
```

this runs our tests fine and by adding following line to karma.config, generate code coverage too.

```
preprocessors: {
'./src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
            , 'src/app/!(lib|shared|styles)/**/!(*spec).ts': 'coverage'
        },
```

however, for some reason it is including coverage for lib/rxjs folder as well. I have tried various combinations in above configs but haven't got any success in excluding that lib folder.

any help is appreciated.

more info - I am only using karma-coverage and not karma-remap-Istanbul.

Comment: Not quite the same scenario as you but I'm using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.24 and generate coverage by running 'ng test --code-coverage'. It includes coverage for polyfills.ts and test.ts which I don't want but then misses coverage for any files that don't have tests - i.e. these should be 0% covered but they're just missing from coverage output.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using karma-remap-istanbul? I came here looking to get coverage enabled and using @EdL's advice, `npm run test -- --code-coverage` worked perfectly (cli 1.0.0-beta.24) and didn't include anything it wasn't supposed to. Perhaps by including that `src/app...` line, it's trying to cover those files and everything else required (including rxjs imports). Just my guess.